# @Retryable annotation in Spring Retry will not fire

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have a table update that causes a deadlock and am trying to get the Spring Retry to retry when the method gets the a locking exception of some kind. I've tried taking out the maxAttempts, value and backoff but it doesn't ever seem to catch any of the exceptions. Am I missing something? Do I need to declare a bean in the Application file? Any help would be much appreciated!

### Application.Java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

### DetailService

```
@Service
public class DetailService {

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, value = { LockAcquisitionException.class, ConcurrencyFailureException.class }, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500, multiplier = 2) )
    public void delete(final String detailCode) {
        try {
            this.delete(this.dao.findByDetailCode(detailCode));
        } catch (LockAcquisitionException | ConcurrencyFailureException e) {
            LOG.warn("Locking error! Going to retry", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void delete(Details detail) {
           this.dao.delete(detail);            
    }

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, value = { LockAcquisitionException.class, ConcurrencyFailureException.class }, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 500, multiplier = 2) )
    public void delete(final Integer id) {
        if (id != null) {
            try {
                this.delete(this.dao.findOne(id));
            } catch (LockAcquisitionException | ConcurrencyFailureException e) { 
                 LOG.warn("Locking error! Going to retry", e.getMessage());
                 throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

### EDIT

Rewrote my DetailService above to give more detail and add missing methods

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are calling the `delete()` method (in the `DetailService`) from within the same class, you are short-circuiting the proxy that Spring wraps the bean in.

The class that has the annotation must be a Spring-managed bean and the `delete()` method must be called from some other Spring-managed bean that has access to the retryable bean via autowiring, injection etc.

**EDIT**

If you need to call the `delete()` method from another method within this class, you can't use the annotation - use a suitably configured `RetryTemplate` instead.

Comment: The delete() method is part of the dao class that is being autowired in. The dao is a crud repository class. Sorry didn't include the whole DetailService class there. Would this still be short circuiting the proxy?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood. No this is not being called within the same class. It's being called from a controller or another service

Comment: No; I mean the `delete()` method in **this** class (the one that's annotated). See my edit for another work around.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint, you should see a proxy and RetryTemplate in the call stack between the controller and this class; if you don't then there's something wrong with the wiring.

Comment: I was mistaken last night, that `delete()` is called by two other methods in the class. If i put the `@Retryable` on those methods will that work? Or do I need to write my own RetryTemplate? I'm trying to avoid the writing my own...

Comment: Yes; as long as the call is from an external bean, `@Retryable` will work. But you don't need to "write" a `RetryTemplate`, just configure one and use it to call the method through one of its `execute` methods.

Comment: Thank you! I was under the assumption that the Retry Template would have a default bean and I didn't need to declare a bean in the Application class. Once I did that `@Retryable` worked.

`@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
`